# how to store incoming data and then output it after a certain delay in simulink

Tags: matlab, queue, delay, simulink, fifo

I have an incoming data and I would like to store it and then Output this data but after a certain delay, after some milliseconds i Output this data.

I used the Queue block inside an enabled Subsystem and the Trigger Signal is the clock divided by 10, So i have evrery time .. every 0.1 second i Output the values from the block,.. but the data is accumulated, not delayed. any idea why?

Here is the Picture of this Operation

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the z^-1 operator produce a delay?

Comment: it does but, i want to store the incoming data and every 110 msec it Outputs the data.. if you put 0.11 which corresponds to 110msec in the delay length in the z^-1 element . it does not work..

Comment: @HeshamMahmoud You are wrongly using the Queue block. Thats why it doesnt work. You dont need to enable the subsistem. What you need is to tell Queue "pop" and "push". Read more about how the block works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** You now show how are you storing the signal. And The queue block is used wrongly.

If you want just to delay a signal, and output it delayed, then use my answer below. I am unsure what you mean by store it by N time and then output it. Simulink is "continuous" thus you can not output it "in one go" after N time, that makes no sense. The closest thing to that is to delay the singal, and for that, you dont need that enabled subsystem, you just need the Transport delay block.

**ORIGINAL**

What about the [Transport Delay block](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transportdelay.html?refresh=true)?

It looks like this:

[image]

and It allows you to set the delay time in seconds, isntead of in ticks [(as z^-1 does)](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/unitdelay.html).

[image]

Comment: yes, I am using it already in my model.. have alook at the Picture i attached.. I just want to know if the Operation i would like to do is the same as what the blocks do or not..

Comment: The idea i am trying to implement, is to check the Simulation time and every 110 msec, which corresponds to 0.11 seconds .. if this is true ,it stores the data in a Queue and then doing a delay with a certain amount (Transport Delay block )

Comment: @HeshamMahmoud I am unsure what you are asking for. You havea blovk that only works after 0.1 seconds, and you want to do what with the output of that block? delay it even more? this will work. Are you sure that you are asking "how to delay a signal?" If so, this is the asnwer. Else, you may have asked a XY question. Make sure you ask what you want, not what you tried.